# (HTML) How do i create a form that redirects to webpages dependant on answer?

Tags: html, forms, redirect

I apologize if this question has been asked before, i can't figure out an easy way to put this.
I am trying to creating a form on my website that redirects to "easter egg" pages dependent on the word entered on the form, and redirects to a "wrong" page when entering an answer other than the correct codes. (For example: Entering "Banana" would take you to banana.html, and entering "Strawberry" would take you to strawberry.html but entering anything else like "Tomato" or "lkjhgfdsa" will take you to wrong.html)
I cannot entirely comprehend the HTML Form lectures at W3Schools to create something like this, but at least i know exactly how i can create a form.
But can someone tell me how i can create an "answer-dependant" form as how i described? I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: How can you tell whether the input is correct or wrong?

Comment: A little JavaScript (if it doesn't need to be particularly secure) or some server-side code (PHP, Ruby, etc.) if it does.

Comment: Please provide the code that you've written so far. Also, the question has nothing to do with css - please edit your titile and tags.

Comment: @RichardYan I haven't written anything, only the input type and that's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to code the form to start with, once you've done that you'll have to get the PHP response, then check and redirect depending on the input.

```
$response = $_POST['input_name'];

if ($response = 'something') {
     header("location: example.com");
}
else if ($response == 'something else') {
    header("location: other.example.com");
}
```

Comment: How exactly do i enter that PHP code? When i do the code is displayed as text on the site.
And how would i have "something else" be any word other than the given word?

Comment: @sodaddict These are all extremely basic questions that are answered by learning PHP. a) It depends on your code. b) That's up to you. c) A simple `else` statement.